# Is there a way to connect a TSNClock which is simulated in Omnetpp to a real network node?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to connect a simulated TSNClock to a real network/node.[Gateway to real network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvQ2O.png).
The TSNClock sends gPTP-Packets to the gateway which should forward them to a destination in the real world. This is done using the emulation support in [INET](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/emulation/index.html). When monitoring the specified interface using wireshark the TSN Messages do not appear.

I tried to do this similar to the [Videostreaming-Showcase](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/master/showcases/emulation/videostreaming). The videostreaming showcase uses ip adresses to forward the packets. The TSNClock however sends gPTP Packets which are based on Ethernet and uses Mac-adresses.

The TSNClock sends its message to the gateway node, but it doesn´t send the message to the "real"(tapa device) interface.

This is my omnetpp.ini file:

```
[General]
sim-time-limit = 1s
description = "abstract"
scheduler-class = "inet::RealTimeScheduler"
# enable time synchronization in all network nodes
*.*.hasTimeSynchronization = true


# all Ethernet interfaces have 100 Mbps speed
*.*.eth[*].bitrate = 100Mbps

[Config OneMasterClock]
network = OneMasterClockGptpShowcase
description = "Test"

**.crcMode = "computed"
**.fcsMode = "computed"

*.gateway.multicastForwarding = true
*.gateway.forwarding = true

*.gateway.eth[1].typename = "ExtLowerEthernetInterface"
*.gateway.eth[1].copyConfiguration = "copyFromExt"
*.gateway.eth[1].device = "tapa"

*.gateway.eth[0].typename = "EthernetInterface"

# TSN clock gPTP master ports
*.tsnClock.gptp.masterPorts = ["eth0"]

# Set all reference clocks to master clock so the time difference can be visualized
**.referenceClock = "tsnClock.clock"
```

and this is the ned file

```
network OneMasterClockGptpShowcase extends TsnNetworkBase
{
    submodules:
        tsnClock: TsnClock {
            @display("p=500,150");
        }

        gateway: Router {
            parameters:
                @display("p=500,400");
                            
        }

    connections:
        tsnClock.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> gateway.ethg++;
       

}
```

Could the problem be the adressing via mac-adresses and is it possible to create a mac-routingtable like the ipv4 nat table in the videostreaming showcase? Is this the right approach or are there other ways to achieve the goal to send the gPTP Messages into a real network?